# Reactivate a value after toggling it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

I'm new to React, and I'm struggling with this problem:

My application has three optional numerical inputs, and when I choose to disable them I set their values to 0. However, when I reactivate them, I want them to revert to their previous state (not 0).

I could probably solve this by having two states, one with the actual value, and one that is being displayed, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to go. Then I would need to keep track of two states at once. My application has enough states as it is, and I figure that you guys know of a better solution than what I've just written.

```
this.state = {
    ...,
    optionals:  {
        A: {
            value: 800,
            displayValue: 0,
            isEnabled: false
        },
        B: {
            value: 27,
            displayValue: 27,
            isEnabled: true
        },
        C: {
            value: 90,
            displayValue: 90,
            isEnabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

Also, is it bad practice to have so nested states?

Here's my desired behavior for an optional input:
[reactivating value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn7Cf.png)

---

Edit:

This is what it currently looks like. I opted for Dominic Tobias' answer for the time being.
**The app's states**

```
this.state = {
    ...other things,
    optionals:  {
        A: {
            value: 800,
            isEnabled: false
        },
        B: {
            value: 27,
            isEnabled: true
        },
        C: {
            value: 90,
            isEnabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

**The html**

```
<input type="number" defaultValue={this.state.optionals.A.value} onChange="this.onAChanged.bind(this)" />
<input type="number" defaultValue={this.state.optionals.B.value} onChange="this.onBChanged.bind(this)" />
<input type="number" defaultValue={this.state.optionals.C.value} onChange="this.onCChanged.bind(this)" />
<Chart data={
    [
        A.isEnabled ? A.value : 0,
        B.isEnabled ? B.value : 0,
        C.isEnabled ? C.value : 0
    ]
}/>
<Toggle onChange="this.toggleA.bind(this)"/>
<Toggle onChange="this.toggleB.bind(this)"/>
<Toggle onChange="this.toggleC.bind(this)"/>
```

**The methods for onChange**

```
onAChange(e) {
    const{ value } = e.target;
    const AValue = value === '' ? this.state.optionals.A.value : Number(value);
    if(typeof AValue === 'number' && value >=1) {
    this.setState(prevState => (
        {
        ...prevState,
        optionals: {
            ...prevState.optionals,
            A: {
                ...prevState.optionals.A,
                value: Avalue
            }
        }
        })); 
    }
}

toggleA(e) {
    const { checked } = e.target;

    this.setState(prevState => (
        {
            ...prevState,
            optionals: {
                ...prevState.optionals,
                A: {
                    ...prevState.optionals.A,
                    isEnabled: checked
                }
            }
        }));
}
```

- What Jayavel shows is pretty much what I want to do. `isEnabled` will decide whether the value is going to be displayed.
- What I have works, but the methods don't seem to be so elegant, because the values are three levels deeply nested. `onAChange`, `onBChange`, and `onCChange` all do the same things, is there a way to simplify this? `toggleA`, `toggleB`, and `toggleC` as well...

Thank you for your help so far! I really appreciate it, and sorry for any confusion.

Comment: u can manage using only one state,Please provide some html

Comment: If the disabled value is a constant you can just do: `<input value={disabled ? '0' : value} .../>`

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What does 'isEnabled' do? Doesn't it control whether the value is displayed or not? What is the difference between value and displayValue? Please describe the process: e.g. you set the value to X and isEnabled to true, this displays the value. You change isEnabled to false, etc.

Comment: The next step for making your code more "elegant" would be to separate each toogle + input into its own component. Let it have a prop for `value` and a prop which is an event handler where you inject which state (value) to change in the parent's values :)
Let me know if you want an example :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need something like below :

[image]

Is that what you need? I made a demo on this and put some code. It will help us to understand what's your problem.

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kk7caq)